# C# - string ReadLine without new line

Tags: c#, newline, readline

Can I do ReadLine in C# (I wanna read to string) without that invisible "\n" just before ReadLine?

I wanna this to look like that:

> Type name:
>   $> (user types here)

But while using ReadLine, I get this:

> Type name:
> $>
> (user types here).

How can I change cursor position to go back line?

Comment: Do you mean `Console.Write("$>")`?

Comment: Well if you could show us your current code, we could help you. My guess is that it's not `ReadLine` that's the problem, but `WriteLine`... try using `Console.Write("$> ");` instead of my *guess* as to your code which is `Console.WriteLine("$> ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you writing the text to prompt the user?  For this behavior you should be using [Console.Write()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hebffx2d(v=vs.110).aspx), not .WriteLine() to leave the cursor at the end of the string written to the console.

See also [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/6518/diffrence-between-write-and-writeline-methods-in-C-Sharp.aspx) explaining it further

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should consider  Console.SetCursorPosition

Comment: But how exacly? When I put it before, it still goes line down from the place I put it, and when I put it after, it comes to that position after I type the text.

Comment: something like:
string result = "test";
Console.Write(result);
Console.SetCursorPosition(result.Length, 0);